# Write F# code in oop style

Tags: c#, f#

I wrote an ip calculator library mixin functional and oop style together.

```
type IpAddr(file: string, loc: string) = 

    let location = queryIpLocation file loc
    let listRange = extractAddr location 


    member self.Calculate(addr :string) =
        validIp addr listRange
```

The calculate method return a record type:

```
type IpLoc =
     { ip : String
       subnet : String
       gateway : String }
```

Then I imported the library into C# application and want to use the class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var calc = new IpAddr(@"C:\Temp\file.xml", "xxxxxxx");
        var ip = calc.Calculate("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
        Console.WriteLine(ip);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The calculate method return an option object of type IpLoc. Now I do not know how to handle the option object in C#.

My target is, to write libraries for .net application for my company in f# and gui wpf based on C#. Why not only in C#,
because I want to discover the power of f#, but it is a good idea to go in this way?

Comment: First answer - why do you want to use a functional language to create plain-old OO-style code? Why did you choose F# in the first place? You won't get any benefit from "the power of F#" if you use it as if it were C#. Second, the library's API doesn't need to (shouldn't?) use F#-specific types. This means- no options in the *API*. You can use all of F#'s features in the implementation, but only expose a C#-compatible API

Comment: The `C#-compatible API` as you mentioned above, it is an good idea to return an object?

Comment: What do you mean? Everything is essentially an object in both languages. Some types may use value semantics some not, but they are all objects. I think you should clarify what you are doing and why. Unless you know why you are using F# and what you want to expose to clients, you'll simply end up with not-quite-readable C# code masquerading as F#

Comment: I want to write data processing in f#, for example query database table or calculate some stuff. I think for data processing is f# a better choice, then c#. In c#, i am tired from typing. But WPF and c# works like charm with each other. What I want to know is, to write api for processing data in f# it is a good idea? I hear, parallel programming in f# it is amazing.

Comment: @zero_coding Is the problem that `Calculate` returns F# option type? If so, please make that more explicit in the question - I think people are voting to close it because they missed the short note about the specific problem you're solving.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Is this the right link to your blog? You linked one about optional parameters, but I thought you also had one about extension methods for dealing with options in C# (like `Match` extension or something like that)?

Comment: @TomasPetricek ah, you're right, I pointed to the wrong post. I'll fix that, thanks :)

Comment: About using the F# option type in C#, see http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/10/10-reasons-to-use-f-runtime-in-your-c.html

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think that using F# for writing the library that does the calculations and then wrapping it in a C#-friendly API that can be used from a WPF application is a good idea.

I assume that the problem is that the result of `Calculate` is `option<IpLoc>`.
In general, you can either find some way of dealing with option values from C#. This is not too hard (and probably a good option if you're the only person writing the code).However, C# does not typically use options, so you can also wrap the code into something that would be idiomatic C#.

You can use `Unchecked.defaultof` to return `null`. This is dangerous from the F# perspective, but sometimes it is what C# code expects:

```
  member x.Calculate(b) =
    match valueIp b with
    | Some v -> v
    | None -> Unchecked.defaultof<_>
```

Another option is to create a method that returns `bool` and returns the value via an `out` parameter. This is similar to how `Int32.TryParse` works:

```
  member x.Calculate(b, [<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out>] ipLoc:byref<_>) =
    match valueIp b with
    | Some v -> ipLoc <- v; true
    | None -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your F# library interact with other .NET languages it makes sense to take a look at this document:
["Guidelines for Libraries for Use from other .NET Languages"](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/#guidelines-for-libraries-for-use-from-other-net-languages)